# How to record the movement of an image with the mouse?

Tags: video, video-editor, animation

So, I'm not really into video editing, but I wanted to know, is there a way for example, when you hold and drag an image on an image editor, but record that movement that you do, but I can't record an image software since there's a lot of stuffs going on, I just wanted to get a video from the image with that. Hope made sense, I want to do this to do some animation things

Edit: Something like this, but recorded to a video editor, in real time:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OfOGT0EGxNq-23CAmEkmGqGFAq4qSEKL

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, it really isn't clear what you are asking. Can you post a sketch or other example of what you are trying?

Comment: I edited a link to kinda what I wanted to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a brilliant demonstration of yours I must say :D
This is possible in after effects using the "sketch movement". Just set the image as the target and record the movement.

Comment: Hmmm I just tried after effects haha, where do I find that? Also searching in google didn't help much

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGYYNIGG49Y